# How to continue executing a Neo4J Cypher request after MATCH is not matched?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following params in my Neo4J:

```
{
  "lists": [
    {
      "from": "someone",
      "to": "somebody"
    }
  ]
}
```

And the following query:

```
MATCH (c:Concept{name:'infranodus'}) WITH c, $lists AS list
UNWIND CASE WHEN list = [{}] THEN [null] ELSE list END AS l 
WITH l 
MATCH (cp1:Concept{name:l.from}) 
WITH cp1 
MATCH (cp2:Concept{name:'somebody'}) 
RETURN cp1,cp2;
```

The query above will work.

However, if I replace `l.from` with a non-existent parameter, e.g. `l.about`, then — as the match doesn't happen — the second `cp2` match doesn't fire.

How can I change this behavior and continue executing this query even if `cp1` is not found? Maybe there's a way to pass on a dummy variable as a result?

```
MATCH (c:Concept{name:'infranodus'}) WITH c, $lists AS list
UNWIND CASE WHEN list = [{}] THEN [null] ELSE list END AS l 
WITH l
MATCH (cp1:Concept{name:l.about}) 
WITH cp1 
MATCH (cp2:Concept{name:'somebody'}) 
RETURN cp1,cp2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OPTIONAL MATCH.  If there is no match is found, then it will use NULL for the missing part of the pattern. It is similar to outer join in SQL.

```
NEW:
OPTIONAL MATCH (cp1:Concept{name:l.about}) 

OLD:
MATCH (cp1:Concept{name:l.about})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe replace it with an `IN` predicate ?

For eg :

```
WITH {from: 'Matt Olg', about: 'Matthew Olg'}
AS l
MATCH (n:Person)
WHERE n.name IN [l.from, l.to]
RETURN n.name

╒══════════╕
│"n.name"  │
╞══════════╡
│"Matt Olg"│
└──────────┘
```

[image]